# Why must JSR303 custom annotation's constrain group default to empty array?

Tags: bean-validation, custom-validators

I'm writing a custom validator for a specific constrain group (not Default), but the runtime gives me the below error.

I'm just curious why they need the default values to be empty. Appreciate if you can share your opinion. Thanks :)

xxx.model.validation.CustomValidation contains Constraint annotation, but the groups parameter default value is not the empty array.

StackTrace:    org.hibernate.validator.metadata.ConstraintHelper.assertGroupsParameterExists(ConstraintHelper.java:335)
    org.hibernate.validator.metadata.ConstraintHelper.isConstraintAnnotation(ConstraintHelper.java:282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out in which scenario it can be useful to bind a constraint to a specific group.

A group is used for partial validation (and sequence validation). If you have 10 fields in a class you can mark 8 of them with **A** and 2 with **B**. Then you can decide to validate only the fields in the **A** group or in the **B** group. Conversely you want that `@MyConstraint` belongs to a specific group named **C**. It makes no sense. A group is more or less a name used to distinguish some fields from others in the same class. It has no absolute meaning. Groups are useful in validation not in constraint definition, they are related to fields not to constraints.

Furthermore if you hide the group name in the constraint definition you may run into errors because you can think that the fields are validated all togheter.

```
@Email
private String mail;

@Password
private String pass;

@VAT
private String vatCode;
```

Are you able to see if there is a partial validation?

**EDIT**

In relation to the second comment:
Suppose you have a class with 5 fields with no constraint at all. Three of them are integers. If you want to validate the sum of these three fields you have to create a class-level constraint as you suggest. In this way your custom annotation is applied to the class not to fields so, how can you define groups on fields?

Instead, you may use something like this:

```
@Sum(min = 250, fields = {"length", "width", "height"})
public class MyClass {
    private String type;
    private String code;
    private int length;
    private int width;
    private int height;
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alf. Your last point about **"hide the group name in the constraint definition you may run into errors"** is valid enough. It it indeed indistinguishable if @VAT were a custom constrain with default group different from Default - thus causing confusion & error.

Comment: I'm not really understand your first point though. I have fields with group A, B representing different set of validation rules. However for group B, there are some custom validation that I need to perform on multiple fields (e.g. their sum must higher than some minimum), thus I wrote a custom validator/constraint on the model itself (i.e. Target: ElementType.TYPE). This custom validator is mean for group B ONLY, thus I tried to put B as the default constraint group.